# Javascript remove connected items in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some js arrays. For example:

```
var array1 ="Apple","Orange","Lemon";
var array2 ="Shop1","Shop2","Shop3";
var array3 ="1","NA","4";
var finalArray=[];
finalArray.push(array1,array2,array3);
```

The items in each array are linked as I am using them to generate a chart. However, how can remove linked items from finalArray so that if array3 contains 'NA' then each linked item is removed from finalArray. Thus finalArray would contain:

```
array1 ="Apple","Orange";
array2 ="Shop1","Shop3";
array3 ="1","4";
```

Any help or pointers in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: I won't downvote, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: This `var array1 ="Apple","Orange","Lemon";` won't define an array and will thrown an error...

Comment: in this context, what does **linked** mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Here idea is

- Loop through the array3 and check whether the value of particular element is `NA` or not.
- If it's not `NA` push the values to respective keys.
- If it's `NA` just simply return op without any change.

```js
var array1 =["Apple","Orange","Lemon"];
var array2 =["Shop1","Shop2","Shop3"];
var array3 =["1","NA","4"];

var finalArray = array3.reduce((op,inp,index) => {
  if( inp != 'NA') {
    op.array1.push(array1[index])
    op.array2.push(array2[index])
    op.array3.push(inp)
  }
  return op
},{array1:[], array2:[], array3:[]})

console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array with the flags from the end and splice all arrays of `finalArray`.

```js
var array1 = ["Apple", "Orange", "Lemon"],
    array2 = ["Shop1", "Shop2", "Shop3"],
    array3 = ["1", "NA", "4"],
    finalArray = [array1, array2, array3],
    i = array3.length;

while (i--) {
    if (array3[i] !== 'NA') continue;
    finalArray.forEach(a => a.splice(i, 1));
}

console.log(finalArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```